# using qq map tiles with the leaflet.js :Uncaught Error: No value provided for variable {x16}

Tags: leaflet, cartography

I tried to use qq map tiles with the leaflet.js but it has an error "Uncaught Error: No value provided for variable {x16}" and cannot show map.

My code

```
var map = L.map('map');
 map.setView([39.948106,116.2652916], 11);


     L.TileLayer.WebDogTileLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
     getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {
         var urlArgs,
             getUrlArgs = this.options.getUrlArgs;

         if (getUrlArgs) {
             var urlArgs = getUrlArgs(tilePoint);
         } else {
             urlArgs = {
                 z: tilePoint.z,
                 x: tilePoint.x,
                 y: tilePoint.y
             };
         }

         return L.Util.template(this._url, L.extend(urlArgs, this.options, {s: this._getSubdomain(tilePoint)}));
     }
 });

 L.tileLayer.webdogTileLayer = function (url, options) {
     return new L.TileLayer.WebDogTileLayer(url, options);
 };
 var url = 'http://p{s}.map.gtimg.com/demTiles/{z}/{x16}/{y16}/{x}_{y}.jpg',
     options = {
         subdomain: '012',
         getUrlArgs: function (tilePoint) {
             return {
                 z: tilePoint.z,
                 x: tilePoint.x,
                 y: Math.pow(2, tilePoint.z) - 1 - tilePoint.y
             };
         }        
     };
 L.tileLayer.webdogTileLayer(url, options).addTo(map);
```

How to solve it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/VhYnmd?p=preview

Comment: Does It must put code in my post ?  I put my code in plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is option. I solve this issue.